# Remover a: do xml gerado pelo meu web service

Tags: xml, web-service, rest, wcf, xml-namespaces

Quando gero o XML em um web service rest, aparece assim:

```
<getCnpjParceiroResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <getCnpjParceiroResult 
        xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/V99SuporteTecnicoContracts" 
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Bairro>SAO VICENTE</a:Bairro>
        <a:CEP i:nil="true"/>
        <a:CNPJ>11951604000130</a:CNPJ>
        <a:CaminhoLogo/>
        <a:Celular i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Cidade>PIRACICABA</a:Cidade>
        <a:Complemento i:nil="true"/>
        <a:DDD>0</a:DDD>
        <a:DDDCelular>0</a:DDDCelular>
        <a:DataAlteracao>0001-01-01T00:00:00</a:DataAlteracao>
        <a:DataCadastro>0001-01-01T00:00:00</a:DataCadastro>
        <a:Distrito i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Email i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Endereco>AV. CRISTOVAO COLOMBO</a:Endereco>
        <a:EnderecoIPInstalacao i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Estado i:nil="true"/>
        <a:IDPdv>0</a:IDPdv>
        <a:IDTipoEstabelecimento>0</a:IDTipoEstabelecimento>
        <a:IDTipoRede>0</a:IDTipoRede>
        <a:ID_Rede>0</a:ID_Rede>
        <a:IS_Ativo>false</a:IS_Ativo>
        <a:Latitude>0</a:Latitude>
        <a:Longitude>0</a:Longitude>
        <a:NomeFantasia i:nil="true"/>
        <a:NomeRede i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Numero i:nil="true"/>
        <a:QtdeCheckOuts>0</a:QtdeCheckOuts>
        <a:RazaoSocial>CONVENIENCIA RADIAL NORTE SUL LTDA EPP</a:RazaoSocial>
        <a:Telefone i:nil="true"/>
        <a:TokenAuthentication i:nil="true"/>
    </getCnpjParceiroResult>
</getCnpjParceiroResponse>
```

Comment: Nota ao editor: @helderdarocha, não devemos *nunca* adicionar ou remover nada ao código original postado numa pergunta pois isso pode consertar o erro ou introduzir outros problemas. Acertar a indentação e remover linhas em branco é ok.

Comment: @brasofilo Não foi introduzido ou removido nada do código original. Ele foi apenas endentado. A única coisa acrescentada foi um tag, [tag:xml-namespaces], que é relevante para a questão.

Comment: Agora vi @brasofilo. Desculpe. Eu usei uma ferramenta para endentar o código e ela introduziu uma declaração XML. Não tinha percebido. De qualquer forma isto não interfere no problema em questão.

Comment: O [original](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/16900/1) não tinha a tag de abertura `<xml../>`. Se o arquivo está sendo gerado sem isso, é um outro problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare

Antes estava assim:

BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped

Answer (score 3):

se quiser um jeito prático e rápido,
use o método Replace da classe String ou StringBuilder (mais rápido):

```
string xml = new StringBuilder(xmlContent);
xml.Replace("<a:", "<");
xml.Replace("</:a", "</");
xmlContent = xml.ToString();
```

mas aconselho você a ler o xml por uma classe especializada `XmlReader` ou parecida, (explicação aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader.read)
e apenas substituir os nomes para evitar problemas com o "corpo" do arquivo.

Comment: Se for fazer isto teria que também remover o sufixo da declaração `xmlns:a`, caso contrário os elementos perderão sua associação com o namespace e não poderão ser validados.

Answer (score 3):

O prefixo `a:` antes desses elementos declara que eles pertencem a um *namespace*. Isto não faz parte do nome do elemento. Você *não pode simplesmente removê-los* sem fazer alterações em outras partes do arquivo ou seu documento poderá ficar inválido.

Se você realmente precisar remover os prefixos, você terá que alterar também a declaração `xmlns:a` que está em `<getCnpjParceiroResult>`. Essa declaração associa todos os elementos descendentes que têm prefixo `a` pertencem ao namespace `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/V99SuporteTecnicoContracts"`. Como não há elementos *sem* o prefixo `a` dentre os descendentes de `<getCnpjParceiroResult>`, você pode estabelecer esse namespace como o *default*, o que permite que elementos sejam declarados sem prefixo.

Portanto, para que seu documento continue válido e não tenha os prefixos `a` o namespace deve ser declarado usando `xmlns` (sem sufixo):

```
<getCnpjParceiroResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <getCnpjParceiroResult 
        xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/V99SuporteTecnicoContracts" 
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Bairro>SAO VICENTE</Bairro>
        <CEP i:nil="true"/>
        <CNPJ>11951604000130</CNPJ>
        <CaminhoLogo/>
        <Celular i:nil="true"/>
        ...
        <Telefone i:nil="true"/>
        <TokenAuthentication i:nil="true"/>
    </getCnpjParceiroResult>
</getCnpjParceiroResponse>
```

Quanto à geração do XML, você precisa descobrir como configurar isto no software que o gera. Deve haver algum mapa ou registro onde você possa associar prefixos com namespaces, ou escolher preferências. De qualquer forma, *não existe nenhuma diferença* em termos funcionais para tags com prefixo ou sem, a menos que você esteja usando tecnologias que não suportem namespaces. Os dois XMLs, o seu com prefixo `a`, o que postei acima sem o prefixo, ou ainda um outro declarando um prefixo diferente (ex: `<datacontract:cnpj>`) serão equivalentes e igualmente válidos se a associação for para o mesmo namespace.

Comment: helderdarocha, bom dia. Eu tenho essa informação após o documento ser gerado. Há como antes da geração desse documento, eu fazer algo que impeça tag a? O problema que a empresa parceira que vai consumir esse web service, a programadora lá disse que essa tag aestá dando problemas. Poderia dizer que isso é problema dela e etc, mas gosto de aplanar os caminhos, então, se puder falitar do meu lado farei.

Comment: Eu não sei se é trivial com WCF. Eu encontrei [este artigo](http://vanacosmin.ro/Articles/Read/WCFEnvelopeNamespacePrefix). Se ficar muito complicado, você pode escrever um interceptador que arranque os prefixos `a:` e o sufixo do `xmlns:a` como foi proposto na outra resposta, já que não existe um namespace default previamente definido.